# Soma de valores do <select> inseridos no <input>

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, typescript

Estou dando uma praticada em ionic 2, estou construindo um app básico para isso, com algumas funções interessantes para estudar.

Quero que, quado o usuário selecionar duas "ion-option" de dois "ion-select" diferentes, esses resultados (em números) sejam somados e mostrados no "input" ou outro elemento HTML que recomendarem.

Fiz esse código até agora sozinho:

```
export class HomePage {
  public racas:string;
  teste() {
      if (this.racas == "humanos") {
        (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("pv")).innerHTML = "2";
      }else if (this.racas =="anoes") {
        (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("pv")).innerHTML = "0";
      }
  }

  public classes:string;
  pontosVida() {
    if (this.classes == "barbaro") {
      (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("pv")).innerHTML = "3";
    }else if (this.racas =="anoes") {
        (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("pv")).innerHTML = "0";
      }
  }
}
```

Sei que essa forma está errada, mas ainda não sei a certa, quero que some os valores, nesse caso, de "humanos"(2) e "barbaro"(3).

HTML

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item>
     <ion-label>Classe</ion-label>
       <ion-select id="classes" [(ngModel)]="classes" (ionChange)="pontosVida();">
         <ion-option value="barbaro">Bárbaro</ion-option>
         <ion-option value="bardo">Bardo</ion-option>
         <ion-option value="clerigo">Clérigo</ion-option>
         <ion-option value="druida">Druida</ion-option>
         <ion-option value="feiticeiro">Feiticeiro</ion-option>
         <ion-option value="guerreiro">Guerreiro</ion-option>
         <ion-option value="ladino">Ladino</ion-option>
         <ion-option value="mago">Mago</ion-option>
         <ion-option value="monge">Monge</ion-option>
         <ion-option value="paladino">Paladino</ion-option>
         <ion-option value="ranger">Ranger</ion-option>
       </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

  <ion-list>
   <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Raças</ion-label>
      <ion-select id="racas" [(ngModel)]="racas" (ionChange)="teste();">
        <ion-option value="humanos">Humanos</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="anoes">Anões</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="elfos">Elfos</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="gnomos">Gnomos</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="meio-elfos">Meio-elfos</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="meio-orcs">Meio-orcs</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="halfling">Halfling</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

  <ion-row class="colunas-principais">
    <ion-col width-33>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item text-center>
          <ion-input id="ca" type="text" name="ca"></ion-input>
          <ion-label stacked>CA</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-col>

    <ion-col width-33>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item text-center>
          <ion-input id="pv" type="text" [value]="pontos"></ion-input>
          <ion-label stacked>PV</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-col>

    <ion-col width-33>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item text-center>
          <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
          <ion-label stacked>IN</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```

Se puderem ajudar, agradeço muito!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não acesse/manipule o `DOM` diretamente, isso pode ocasionar problemas de [segurança](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/security.html). Para isso, utilize o `decorator` [`@ViewChild`](http://learnangular2.com/viewChild/) ou um `bind` através da diretiva `[(ngModel)]`:

`html:`

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Stack</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
<ion-list>
    <ion-item>
     <ion-label>Classe</ion-label>
       <ion-select id="classes" [(ngModel)]="classes" (ionChange)="pontosVida();">
         <ion-option value="barbaro">Bárbaro</ion-option>
         <ion-option value="bardo">Bardo</ion-option>
         <ion-option value="clerigo">Clérigo</ion-option>
         <ion-option value="druida">Druida</ion-option>
         <ion-option value="feiticeiro">Feiticeiro</ion-option>
         <ion-option value="guerreiro">Guerreiro</ion-option>
         <ion-option value="ladino">Ladino</ion-option>
         <ion-option value="mago">Mago</ion-option>
         <ion-option value="monge">Monge</ion-option>
         <ion-option value="paladino">Paladino</ion-option>
         <ion-option value="ranger">Ranger</ion-option>
       </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

  <ion-list>
   <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Raças</ion-label>
      <ion-select id="racas" [(ngModel)]="racas" (ionChange)="teste();">
        <ion-option value="humanos">Humanos</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="anoes">Anões</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="elfos">Elfos</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="gnomos">Gnomos</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="meio-elfos">Meio-elfos</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="meio-orcs">Meio-orcs</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="halfling">Halfling</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

  <ion-row class="colunas-principais">
    <ion-col width-33>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item text-center>
          <ion-input id="ca" type="text" name="ca"></ion-input>
          <ion-label stacked>CA</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-col>

    <ion-col width-33>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item text-center>
          <ion-input id="pv" type="text" [(ngModel)]="pv" [value]="pontos"></ion-input>
          <ion-label stacked>PV</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-col>

    <ion-col width-33>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item text-center>
          <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
          <ion-label stacked>IN</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-content>
```

`ts:`

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'pages/home/home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  public racas:string;
  public classes:string;


  public pv: number = 0;
  public pvRaca: number = 0;
  public pvClasse: number = 0;

  teste() {

    switch(this.racas) {
      case 'humanos':
        this.pvRaca = 2;
        break;
      default:
        this.pvRaca = 0;
        break;
    }

    this.calculaPV();
  }

  pontosVida() {
    switch(this.classes) {
      case 'barbaro':
        this.pvClasse = 3;
        break;
      default:
        this.pvClasse = 0;
        break;
    }

    this.calculaPV();
  }


  calculaPV() {
    this.pv = this.pvRaca + this.pvClasse;
  }


}
```

Veja no [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/rz6rDy?p=preview)

Comment: Marcelo, muito obrigado! Aprendi muito mais agora do que em vários vídeos do Youtube :)

Comment: Só me esclarece mais uma coisa, nesse exemplo, você importou o @ViewChild mas não utilizou certo? Nesse caso você só usou o a diretiva [(ngModel)]?

Comment: Isso, esqueci de remover o `import`